# Restricting whole django app to the normal users

Tags: django, django-views

I am not using django built-in admin panel for the admin page but I am trying to add functionality like django-admin.I want to restrict normal users to the admin app and for this I check like this  `if not request.user.is_superuser` in every function where I want to restrict.It does the job pretty well but in the app there can be so many functions and i have to check this in every function inside the app and I think this should not be the good solution.So is there any solution so that I can give access the whole admin functionality to only superuser without checking user with `if not request.user.is_superuser` in every function inside the admin app ?

views.py

```
    def a(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('login')
     ..........
    
    def b(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('login')
    .............
    
    def c(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('login')
    ...........
  
    def d(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('login')
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom middleware to achieve this.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class RestrictUserMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path.find("/admin/") > -1:  # restricted admin url for custom admin site
           if not request.user.is_superuser:
              return redirect(reverse('login_url_name'))
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

And use that middleware in SETTINGS file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Other middlewares
    'path.to.RestrictUserMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: `'RestrictUserMiddleware' object has no attribute 'request'` got this error

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: django 2 version

Comment: can you please share the full stacktrace?

Comment: @userme yep, I found the bug. Updated my answer. please try again

Comment: @userme I just re-read your question again. I am not entirely clear on what problem you are facing. Logically, ` if user and user.is_superuser: login(request, user)` is correct, because you want to restrict users from your django application, so only the super users should be allowed to login.

Comment: i want to restrict all the urlpatterns of admin app to normal user and give access to only superuser.For example if somone give url in the address bar like `admin/add/products/` then the user should be redirected to the admin login page if the user is not superuser.

Comment: If you are using django admin, then its already there. If you have custom admin, then I will update the answer shortly

Comment: your updated answer worked but using `reverse` didn't  worked `return redirect('login_url_name')` when i removed the `reverse` then it worked.Thanks for the solution.And One question i didn't understand `> -1` what is it doing

Comment: @userme please check the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find .  Also you check this documentation on reverse as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Answer (score 2):

## custom decorator

#### decorators.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def superuser_only(view_func=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
                          login_url='login'):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in and is a staff
    member, redirecting to the login page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_superuser,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if view_func:
        return actual_decorator(view_func)
    return actual_decorator
```

## To apply `decorator` to all of your urls

#### urls.py

```
def dec_patterns(patterns):
    decorated_patterns = []
    for pattern in patterns:
        callback = pattern.callback
        pattern.callback = superuser_only(callback)
        pattern._callback = superuser_only(callback)
        decorated_patterns.append(pattern)
    return decorated_patterns

url_patterns = [
    path("my-path/", views.my_view),
]
url_patterns = dec_patterns(url_patterns)
```

Comment: i was asking to restrict whole app functions not in some particular function. I already have done that before by adding in each and every function i have

Comment: @userme using `middleware` will have an impact on all apps in the project. It will check for every request. so, it will slowdown the app a little bit.

Comment: override `user_passes_test` functionality. code can be found in django github repo

Comment: where can i find docs about django.urls.path's object?

Comment: @MasZero https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#path

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`user_passes_test()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator with a lambda function.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.http import JsonResponse

# first solution

@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser)
def test_func(request):
    return JsonResponse(data={})

# second solution

def check_user(user):
    # you can do more actions here
    return user.is_superuser

@user_passes_test(check_user)
def test_func(request):
    return JsonResponse(data={})
```

According to your question, simply you can add this `@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser)` line which is the first solution of my answer on top of your functions or can go to second solution if you need to do more things.